# How can I use the scene on FXML controller

Tags: javafx, fxml

```
@FXML
private Pane pane;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    pane.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(....);
}
```

I want set the scene event on the FXMLController class , what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The scene won't be set on the pane until the root element of the FXML is added to a scene graph. In the controller, you have no control over when that will happen, but it has to happen after the `initialize()` method has completed.

The best approach here is to find some other way to register the event; e.g. do you really want to register it on the scene: can you register it on the root element of the FXML-generated node graph instead?

If you really need to access the scene from the controller, you need to register a listener with the scene property of one of the nodes and set the key pressed handler when the scene is initialized. To be really bullet-proof, you should handle the possibility that your pane may be removed from a scene at some point.

```
public void initialize() {
    EventHandler<KeyEvent> sceneKeyPressedHandler = ... ;
    pane.sceneProperty().addListener((ov, oldScene, newScene) -> {
        if (oldScene != null) {
            oldScene.removeEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, sceneKeyPressedHandler);
        }
        if (newScene != null) {
            newScene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, sceneKeyPressedHandler);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```